# clearTimeout() not stopping setTimeout

Tags: javascript, timer, settimeout, cleartimeout

I'm trying to build a really simple timer in Javascript (based on input from an HTML form), and my clearTimeout isn't working-- not even hitting the console.log that I have. In my HTML, to call the clearTimeout, I just have . I'm really not sure why this isn't working-- any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

```
  function settimer(){

hour = document.getElementById('h').value;
minute = document.getElementById('m').value;
sec = document.getElementById('s').value;

hour = hour * 3600000;
minute = minute * 60000;
sec = sec * 1000;
totalTime = hour+minute+sec;

 var timer = setTimeout(function(){alert("Time's up"); }, totalTime);
 }

  function clear(){
    console.log("stopped")
    clearTimeout(timer);
  }
```

Comment: `var timer` only exists inside of `settimer()`. It'll need to be declared outside of the functions for them both to have access to it.

Answer (score 4):

You are declaring your `timer` variable inside a function, so it's scope is only local to that function. It cannot be called outside the function. To fix this, move the variable outside of your function.

> A variable that is declared outside a function definition is a global variable, and its value is accessible and modifiable throughout your program.
>
> A variable that is declared inside a function definition is local. It is created and destroyed every time the function is executed, and it **cannot be accessed by any code outside the function**.

Here's the documentation from Mozilla Developer Network

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bzt2dkta(v=vs.94).aspx

First declare the `timer` and `total_time` variables outside of any function, giving it local scope.

```
var timer;
var total_time;
```

Now, create the function to set the timer. Note that we want to use the `var` keyword to make these variables local to the scope.

```
function setTimer(){

    var hour = +(document.getElementById('h').value) * 3600000;
    var minute = +(document.getElementById('m').value) * 60000;
    var sec = +(document.getElementById('s').value) * 1000;

    totalTime = hour + minute + sec;    // Assign total time to variable
    alert("Time's up");
}
```

Assign the value of timer to `setTimeout`. We can now use the `totalTime` variable as the amount of time.

```
timer = setTimeout(setTimer, totalTime);
```

We can now stop the timer, because it has been given local scope.

```
function clear() {
    console.log("stopped")
    clearTimeout(timer);
}
```

It should work now. Try it again.

Comment: Thanks, Richard. I tried that, but I get an error then saying that totalTime is not defined...I also tried moving everything to within the settimer() function, but that doesn't work, either..

Comment: Just realized you didn't declare totalTime either. You need to declare that as well, to use it in another function

Comment: Thanks, Richard! It's working great now. Turns out, I also needed to change the name of the function-- I think clear is a reserved word?

Answer (score 4):

When using [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var), `timer` is declared as a local variable within `settimer()` and only exists inside of the function's body of statements.

To allow both functions to share access to it, the variable will have to be declared outside of them. `settimer()` can still assign to it, but then `clear()` can access it as well.

```
// declare variable in surrounding scope
var timer;

function settimer() {
    // ...

    // assign to declared variable
    timer = setTimeout(function(){alert("Time's up"); }, totalTime);
}

function clear(){
    console.log("stopped")
    clearTimeout(timer);
}
```

---

Note: The other variables being used, since they're only needed inside `settimer()`, should be declared as locals.

```
function settimer() {
    var hour = document.getElementById('h').value;
    var minute = document.getElementById('m').value;
    var sec = document.getElementById('s').value;

    hour = hour * 3600000;
    minute = minute * 60000;
    sec = sec * 1000;

    var totalTime = hour+minute+sec;

    // ...
}
```

By not really declaring them at all, they'll automatically become global variables.

Related: [What is the function of the var keyword and when to use it (or omit it)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/what-is-the-function-of-the-var-keyword-and-when-to-use-it-or-omit-it)

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution to this. I have hardcoded the values of hour, min and sec, but you can always get them from the desired place

var totalTime;

```
 function settimer(){

    hour = 0;
    minute = 0;
    sec = 2;

    hour = hour * 3600000;
    minute = minute * 60000;
    sec = sec * 1000;
    totalTime = hour+minute+sec;

};

settimer();

 var timer = setTimeout(function(){
     alert("Time's up"); 
     clear();
  }, totalTime);




  function clear(){
    console.log("stopped")
    clearTimeout(timer);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either hoist `timer` outside of the function or instantiate `timer` without declaring it with `var` rendering it a global variable so that it can be accessed by external functions.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```js
//
const elemDemo = document.querySelector(".demo");

//!---: Function
const timeoutId = new (function () {
  let timer;

  this.next = function () {
    timer = window.setTimeout(function () {
      timeoutId.work();
      timeoutId.next();
    }, 500);
  };

  this.work = function () {
    elemDemo.innerHTML += " = +";
  };

  this.stop = function () {
    clearTimeout(timer);
  };
})();
//!---: Function

document.querySelector('.start').addEventListener('click', timeoutId.next);
document.querySelector('.stop').addEventListener('click', timeoutId.stop);

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
    elemDemo.innerHTML = 'Out -';
});
```

```css
:root,
* {
    background-color: #1D1E22;
    color: white;
    font: 1.1em Consolas;
}

button {
    border: 1px solid violet;
    padding: .3rem 2rem;
    width: 8rem;
}
```

```html
<div class='demo'></div>
<br>
<button class='start'>Start</button>
<br>
 <button class='stop'>Stop</button>
```

Codepen [DEMO](https://codepen.io/pedro404/pen/KKZeweO)